# Deploy different from view on local server

Tags: javascript, html, css, netlify

I was building a site and during building I checked it out through live server and everything was OK. Now after deploying on netlify. The site looks different and scattered, what could be causing this

Comment: it's because is Friday the 13th.  Re-elaborate your question with more details please

Answer (score 0):

Because of the different servers that allow certain parameters in the code and in the other not, maybe in live server some of the tags or code that you wrote don't work in netlify.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).